# jQuery catching event then stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following document ready:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(datePickerClass).length !== 0) {
        bootstrapDatepickerSwitcher();
        $(window).on('resize', bootstrapDatepickerSwitcher());
    }
});
```

My function `bootstrapDatepickerSwitcher` switches between datepicker and native picker for mobile devices based on screen size.

I cam currently getting the `too much recursion` issue and I am trying to stop events bubbling.

Inside the called function I want to execute:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

But I am stuck at how to access the event. I have tried:

```
var event = arguments[0];

var event = window.event || arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0];
```

But I keep getting `event is undefined`. I am working with a `use strict` JS file.

Comment: Firstly you should pass the function *reference* to the `resize` handler: `$(window).on('resize', bootstrapDatepickerSwitcher);`. Secondly, it's hard to say the exact cause of the problem, other than you're creating an infinite loop. From the tiny sample you've provided this could be because the `bootstrapDatepickerSwitcher` function itself is causing a `resize` event, although this seems unlikely. We need to see more of your code to help.

Comment: Please give us your `bootstrapDatepickerSwitcher()` function code

Comment: Hi Rory, thanks for the reply! I understand what you say re seeing code but my question was re stopping events bubbling. Reason why I suspect this is that I am using `tempus dominus` datetimepicker and I also set the dates using my JS. I noticed a couple of posts mentioning the `too much recursion` issue and wanted to try to stop bubbling. How do I catch the event inside my function? Thanks

Comment: @TheRealPapa check out my answer. I think this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access event you can get it as a parameter

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(datePickerClass).length !== 0) {
        bootstrapDatepickerSwitcher();
        $(window).on('resize', function(event) {
            bootstrapDatepickerSwitcher(event);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Krzysztof Janiszewski, thanks for this. I added also the event in the `document ready` function and it all works now without `too much recursion`. Thank you!